# A way to make Unity more lightweight?

Tags: unity

I love the look of Unity so much (despite other opinions) but the laptop I want to buy only has 2gb of ram and a Core 2 duo processor, so from what I've heard Ubuntu will be averagely speedy. But I want it to be even more responsive, is there some options of Unity that I can turn off to do so?

Comment: Sorry if I don't feel like writing a detailed answer, you're looking for unity low graphics mode www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/see-just-much-faster-unity-7-low-graphics-mode

Comment: Thank you very much xangua! I just love the look of Unity so much for some reason...hopefully I'll be able to run ace-minesweeper at 30FPS! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fine tune Unity effects you can use [compizconfig-settings-manager.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/compizconfig-settings-manager) If you don't already have it you can install it by first [enabling the Universe Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then installing the package via either the software center or with the command `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

When you run it you will receive a warning as shown below:

[image: caution]

This is the moment when you should consider whether you have a recent [backup](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) This warning exists because many people [got themselves in trouble by disabling the Unity Plugin entirely.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) Since we have current backups, we will click OK and continue.

**I can't stress enough that if you find your self looking at the screen below, DO NOT UNCHECK the box in the left column of the window:**

[image: UnityPlugin]

Most of the heavier effects are handled by compiz Effects - Choose Effects from the right hand column and you should see something like this:

[image: Effects]

Unchecking all the boxes on this page should turn off unnecessary eye candy and result in reasonably good performance. You can of course experiment with other settings and evaluate the impact on performance on your particular system. Personally, I leave Animations and Fading Windows on as they don't seem to have a major impact on performance on my hardware, but turning them off does have a positive impact on performance.

Comment: May I suggest adding how to enable via ccsm: low graphics mode www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/see-just-much-faster-unity-7-low-graphics-mode

Comment: @xangua Of course you can. Never hesitate to  [write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) offering alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

I run unity on a HP 11 g4 Chromebook with similar specifications to what you have mentioned and it is very fast (I have a full lamp stack to test my php code when working away from my desktop). The only issue I run into is hard drive space but that was fixed with an external sd.

Comment: SSD's are a lot faster than HDD's so that's probably the reason why your Ubuntu is so fast. Did yours work fast even before you got an SSD?